# How to restore previous tabs automatically when reloading Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

How can I restore tabs that were previously open on Firefox when I closed it? I would like the tabs to open automatically when I reopen Firefox. I'm using Firefox 75.0 on macOS Catalina v10.15.4.

Google searches have repeatedly lead to the answer that going to Preferences --> General --> ticking Restore previous session will solve the question, as per the screenshot. However, the tickbox does nothing for me. Reticking it also makes no difference. The equivalent settings for reopening tabs for Google Chrome does work for me. I do not think that any of my Firefox extensions would be causing this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command + Shift + N, when used on a blank FireFox page, will restore the tabs from the previous FireFox session. So on the current FireFox session, you can retrieve the old one provided you do not close the current session.